# How do I use GET with PowerShell in Azure Functions?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

The HTTP Trigger sample for PowerShell uses POST but I need to be able to use GET. The software I want to integrate with can only do GET.

The example begins with:

```
$requestBody = Get-Content $req -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I tried `/api/MyFunction?code=stuffstuffstuff==&param1=asdf&param2=1234` expecting that `$requestBody` would be `param1=asdf&param2=1234`. Instead, it's just empty.

I looked at the JavaScript example and had no trouble doing this. On a GET request the querystring parameters are available in `req.query` vs POST which is `req.body`.

Has this possibly not been implemented for PowerShell yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$req_query_param1` and `$req_query_param2` variables

Invoke URL:

```
https://<your funcname>.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerPowerShell1?code=<your code>&test1=test2
```

Function code:

```
$requestBody = Get-Content $req -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

if ($req_query_test1) 
{
    $name = $req_query_test1 
}
Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $res -inputObject "Hello $name"
```

Comment: Oh wow. Don't I feel a bit silly. I had deleted those lines in the beginning once I got my function working the way I wanted it to. I think I'll put in a PR for the code sample to make it a little more obvious for people like me. haha